# What is the best order to take SharePoint 2010 exams in 

Tags: exam, certification

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a recommended order in which to take the SharePoint 2010 exams?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/10942/is-there-a-recommended-order-in-which-to-take-the-sharepoint-2010-exams)

Wondering if there is an optimal order in which to take the SharePoint 2010 exams.

For 2007 taking the infrastructure exams first worked for me.

Comment: you already asked this question http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/10942/is-there-a-recommended-order-in-which-to-take-the-sharepoint-2010-exams

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think it is any "best order". You should go for those exams for which you are skilled, trained and have experience in.
There are currently for exams for SharePoint 2010; TS Dev, Pro Dev, TS Admin and Pro Admin. If you're an admin type of dude then you will likely take the TS admin first and then pro admin. And devs normally takes the TS Dev and then Pro Dev. I've done all four and they are very different all of them - with only one thing in common; the TS exams are focues on knowing key points in the technologies (API's for devs and config options for admins) while the Pro exams requires that you have experience with the platform and can make decisions about a specific scenario (like recommended way of implementing a solution requiring high performance or knowing the correct way to upgrade a farm giving a set of requirements).

Summary; take them in the order that you think that you can successfully complete them. (Note: you only achieve the Pro Admin/Dev "badge" if you take both the TS and PRO certifications)